# Number of compositions of a positive number n, with factors between 1 and a certain number m

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to find the number of compositions of a positive number $n$, with factors between 1 and a certain number $m$.
That is, all the combinations of limited numbers that add up to $n$

$f(n, m)$

For example:

$f(3, 2) = |(1+1+1), (1+2), (2+1)| = 3$

$f(3, 3) = |(1+1+1), (1+2), (2+1), (3)| = 4$

$f(5, 3) = |(1+1+1+1+1), .... , (3+2), (2+3)| = 13$

Reading online I found this formula for calculating the composition, but it works only in some special cases:
$\sum_{k = \lceil n/m \rceil}^{n} \binom{n-1}{k - 1}$

Can someone tell me the general formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general formula. In order to compute $f(n,m)$ quickly, you can write the recurrence relation as a matrix equation. Let $x_n$ be the vector
$$
x_n=\begin{bmatrix}f(n,m)\\f(n-1,m)\\f(n-2,m)\\\vdots\\f(n-m+1,m)\end{bmatrix}
$$
and let $A$ be the $m\times m$ matrix which has ones just below the diagonal, ones on the top row, and zeroes everywhere else. When $m=4,$
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

You can verify that
$$
x_n=Ax_{n-1}
$$
holds for all $n\ge 1$. Iterating this, you get
$$
x_n=A^nx_0=A^n\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$
Therefore, to compute $f(n,m)$ quickly, it suffices to compute $A^n$ quickly, which can be done in $O(m^3\log n)$ time using exponentiation by squaring.

Comment: Fantastic solution! I just think the last line of $ x_ {n} $ should be $ f (n-m, m) $

Answer (score 2):

I was able to callculate $f(m,n)$ quickly by using recurrence:

$$f(n, m)=1\quad \text{if} \quad  n\in\{0,1\}$$
$$f(n, m)=0\quad \text{if} \quad  n<0$$
$$f(n,m)=\sum_{k=1}^m f(n-k,m)$$

...or in Mathematica:

```
f[n_, m_] := 1 /; n == 0 || n == 1

f[n_, m_] := 0 /; n < 0

f[n_, m_] := f[n, m] = Sum[f[n - k, m], {k, 1, m}]
```

This gives accurate results for all your examples and calculates the number of combinations for bigger values of $n,m$ fairly quickly. For example:

$$f(5,3)=13$$

$$f(20,10)=521472$$

$$f(100,20)=633800819629853453628932292608$$

Comment: Fantastic solution! I implemented it in Python, unfortunately in some cases it fails to compute it and generates the error: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison. For example: $f(99999, 3)$

Comment: I'm trying to optimize it or find a closed formula that allows me to calculate it even for large numbers

Comment: @GabrielePicco If you like the solution, please upvote it :) With my approach the recursion depth is equal to $n$ so in your example Python will have to do 99999 recursive calls which will cause the stack to overflow. Even if it had not, the result would have been a number of epic proportions :)

Comment: Yes you are right. The number of recursions is $ n$ x $m $ right? in the example $ f (99999,3) $ should be 99999 x 3 recursion.

Comment: if I know that I will have to apply a module to the result of the function, can I somehow simplify the calculation?

Comment: @GabrielePicco If you check the recurrence formula, the second argument does not change. The depth of recursion is defined by the first argument. But from the technical point of view, it does not matter if the depth is 99999 or 99999$\times$3. The stack will overflow for sure.

Comment: Yes, I can try an iterative version, but I'm afraid it's still too heavy computationally. Assuming to know that the modulo x operator will be applied to the result of $ f (99999,3) $, is there a way to simplify the calculation?